# How can I change the network configuration on Ubuntu 14.04 server?

Tags: networking, 14.04, server

I just installed an Ubuntu 14.04 server, and I've discovered that there is no way to make any changes to the network configuration except by rebooting the server.  This is on a stock install of Ubuntu 14.04 server, installed last week, with no changes made to it, and no new packages installed (since I can't reach apt-get).

ifconfig up/down seems to read from some kind of cache; at least, it ignores any changes I make to /etc/network/interfaces. I tried using it to change from DCHP to static for eth1, and nothing happened; eth1 continued to get its address from DHCP.

/etc/init.d/networking stop/restart/force-reload all fail with no error message.

How is this supposed to work on Ubuntu Server?  Right now, it seems like network changes only take effect with a reboot.

(and please don't give me answers which involve network-manager; this is a headless server with no GUI.  Thanks).

ADDING INFORMATION REQUESTED BELOW:

/etc/network/interfaces originally was:

```
# The primary network interface
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp
```

... this wasn't picking up gateway information from DHCP, even though my Ubuntu laptop picks it up just fine.

So I changed it to:

```
# The primary network interface
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 172.47.23.106
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 172.47.23.1
```

However, after doing ifconfig down/up, the IP address of eth1 did not change and the gateway did not get added to the route table.  On a full restart of the system, the eth1 configuration was picked up just fine.

So it seems that ifconfig up ignores changes to /etc/network/interfaces.

Comment: Have you looked in `/var/log/*`? There should be error messages in `/var/log/syslog` or `/var/log/udev`. Hint: Cause the (mis)behavior, do `ls -rlt /var/log`, then inspect the last many lines of the last few files listed.

Comment: There are no relevant error messages in syslog or udev that I can find.  Running ifconfig up/down generates only the message that ipv6 isn't configured (which it's not, I'm using ipv4).

Comment: Are you running `ifconfig up/down` as `root`, or via `sudo`? If not, networking will be unaffected. What is in your `/etc/network/interfaces` file?

Comment: /etc/network/interfaces: 

# The primary network interface
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 172.47.23.106
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 172.47.23.1

Note that the above took effect just fine on a reboot of the system.

Comment: "Reboot" should be a last resort, I would think. @chili555 has a better answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on follow-ups elsewhere, I found that it is indeed the case that Ubuntu will completely ignore changes in /etc/network/interfaces for a device which was previously defined and then changed.  In order to get it to take a new configuration, you need to run the following:

```
ifdown {device}
ip addr flush dev {device}
ifup {device}
```

This is run between ifdown and ifup.  Ideally, Ubuntu should add the flush to ifup.

Answer (score 4):

The correct way to get the system to re-read and use the changed /etc/network/interfaces file is:

```
sudo ifdown eth1 && sudo ifup -v eth1
```

The '-v' for verbose should produce output to judge if the changes were made successfully. Check:

```
ifconfig
ping -c3 www.google.com
```

Comment: This helped me diagnose the issue, but was not the actual answer.  Hence, vote up but not accepted.