# ifupdown does not perform parallel IPv4 and IPv6 DHCP requests

Tags: networking, dhcp

I have simple Ubuntu-14.04 setup where eth0 can obtain IPv4 and IPv6 address via DHCP. Now following setting works as long as DHCP server gives an IPv4 address. But if I stop DHCP(IPv4) server, the ifup utility continues to wait forever to assign address to eth0. As a result, eth0 will never get an IPv6 address even though IPv6 DHCPv6 server is up and waiting for requests. I think the order for entries matters. Can we make this immaterial of order in which IPv4/IPv6 address are assigned to eth0 via dhclient.

```
root@localhost:~# cat /etc/network/interfaces

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
iface eth0 inet6 dhcp
```

Is there a fix or configuration workaround for this problem. Any tips would be of great help.

Meanwhile, similar configuration on CentOS-7.1 works fine without any issues.

```
DEVICE=eth0
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
ONBOOT=yes
PERSISTENT_DHCLIENT=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
DHCPV6C=yes
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
DHCPV6C=yes
```

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu-14.04 server

Answer (score 1):

**GUI method**

Open Network Connections go to the IPV4 tab and clear the check-box shown below.

[image]

**CLI method**

Edit the file that matches your connection. In my case it's  `NetworkManager/system-connections/Ethernet\ connection\ 1` Your may be different. Look in NetworkManager/system-connections to find it. Look under the IPv4 section and if you have it, remove the line `may-fail=false` (you could change it to true, but when I clear the checkbox in the GUI method above it simply removes the line so that should do it.)

```
[ipv4]
method=auto
may-fail=false
```

Comment: I am using Ubuntu Server. There is no GUI available. Also we are not using NetworkManager. Any other way forward?

Comment: In that case you might find this post helpful: http://askubuntu.com/questions/509975/how-can-i-change-the-network-configuration-on-ubuntu-14-04-server

Comment: I went through the scenario in the suggested link. Unfortunately my case  seems to be different.

Comment: If your not using Network Manager why is it tagged in your post.  Please [edit] your post to reflect your actual situation and actual problem. Thank you for helping us help you!